# python access array errors

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

im working on a an assignment but the few lines keeps on giving me errors that i cannot understand

```
pick=0
final=0
while True:

    if (min_weight>0):

        if (sort_ratio[pick]["Weight"]<min_weight):
            final = final + sort_ratio[pick]["Cost"]
            min_weight = min_weight - sort_ratio[pick]["Weight"]

        if (sort_ratio[pick]["Weight"]>min_weight):
            pick = pick + 1

        if (min_weight == 0):
            print (final)
            return
```

the only problem is when the program pass "pick = pick+ 1" it stops and gives "index out of range" error.

Instead of using the increment method i tried to edit the array instead using

```
sort_ratio.remove(sort_ratio[0]);
```

but it gives me "cannot interpreted as integer problem"

present code

```
from operator import itemgetter
import math

raw_input=input;

test_case = int(raw_input());


for inp1 in range (test_case):
    min_weight = int(raw_input());
    candy_types = int(raw_input());
    candy = [];

for inp2 in range (candy_types):

    can_weight,can_cost = map(int,raw_input().split());

    ratio_candy = (can_cost / int(can_weight));

    candy.extend([{"Cost": can_cost, "Ratio": ratio_candy, "Weight": can_weight}]);

sort_ratio = sorted ( candy, key=itemgetter('Ratio'));
pick = 0;
final = 0;

while True:

    if (min_weight>0):

        if (sort_ratio[pick]["Weight"]<min_weight):
            final = final + sort_ratio[pick]["Cost"]
            min_weight = min_weight - sort_ratio[pick]["Weight"]
            print (final)
            print (min_weight)

        if (sort_ratio[pick]["Weight"]>min_weight):
            pick = pick + 1

        if (min_weight==0):
            print (final)
            break
```

Comment: Is it a knapsack problem?

Comment: please supply us with a functional code snipplet, it is impossible to see what you are trying to do. What is the shape of sort_ratio? At which value of pick are you out of bounds?

Comment: http://sscce.org/ thanks

Comment: yes this is a knapsack problem